# Line breaks not displaying in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Person.description with the following stored in the database:

> jnkl
>
> fdsfdsf
>
> fdsf
>
> fsdfdsfs fds fd sf sdf ds

How do I display this with the line-breaks in the view? It is currently displaying all on one line and I don't understand why.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code from the view.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

you should use the simple_format helper:

```
<%= simple_format @person.description %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

## Source

```
# File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb, line 301
def simple_format(text, html_options = {}, options = {})
  wrapper_tag = options.fetch(:wrapper_tag, :p)

  text = sanitize(text) if options.fetch(:sanitize, true)
  paragraphs = split_paragraphs(text)

  if paragraphs.empty?
    content_tag(wrapper_tag, nil, html_options)
  else
    paragraphs.map! { |paragraph|
      content_tag(wrapper_tag, raw(paragraph), html_options)
    }.join("\n\n").html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: much more simple

Answer (score 27):

The reason why, is that in plain HTML, outside of containing tags such as 'xmp', line breaks aren't rendered as linebreaks, for the most part they are ignored. For them to show up, you need to replace them with 'br' tags, or something else that has a style or structure associated with it, like p tags, or even divs, depending on the content is.

This should do what you ask:

```
@person.description.gsub(/\n/, '<br />')
```

The built in Rails helper simple_format will also work, using p tags

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Answer (score 6):

I also use

```
@person.description.gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe
```

to display them in the view

Comment: and you're not worried about about marking random data from the db as HTML safe?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing \n to `<br>` tags, which would consume a lot of processing if its a huge text, use css `white-space: pre` to break lines on \n.

Source: [An html tag other than a textarea where \n is correctly interpreted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841320/an-html-tag-other-than-a-textarea-where-n-is-correctly-interpreted)

Answer (score 0):

simple_format did not suit my needs as I want to be able to show multiple line breaks. simple_format makes 2 or more line breaks a paragraph.
So, I used css `white-space: break-spaces;` instead. The only current drawback is the browser support is 89.5% now.