# An html tag other than a textarea where \n is correctly interpreted

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<textarea data-bind="text: signaletic()"></textarea>
```

where signaletic is from here:

```
client.signaletic = ko.computed(function () {
    var name = ...
    var address = ...
    var postcode = ...
    var city = ...
    var country = ...
    return name + '\n' + address + '\n' + postcode + ' ' + city + '\n' + country;
});
```

It works, I mean I have a new line between elements thanks to '\n'.

Now I would like to use another control than a textarea, I need a read-only control. I try with a simple div but my '\n' don't work anymore. Does someone have an idea for replacing my textarea with a read-only html element where '\n' is correctly interpreted?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can apply the `white-space: pre` CSS property to force an element to respect newlines.

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` to make lines wrap like in textareas.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `<textarea readonly>blar \n blar \n blar</textarea>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same textarea approach but add the disabled attribute to the textarea. There is a readonly attribute too, then you cannot edit the document but can interact with the textarea control (resize and all). Your choice.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea 
An example (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_disabled.asp) ..